# Automated data frame summaries with mixed data types

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

I am trying to automatically create a new data frame that, given an existing data frame, contains either the median of a numerical variable or the most common category for a factor.  So:

```
Number Factor  
3      A
2      A
5      B
```

Should turn into

```
Number Factor  
3      A
```

I can calculate it for each variable individually. For purely numerical variables I could even use the colMeans command. For purely factor variables I would use which.max(). But I have not been able to combine the two into a scalable and flexibe solution

Comment: I am confused, are you summing the `Number` column for most common factor?

Comment: Surely your median is 3?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. Switched median and mean concepts in my head. Thanks for the cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can test something like that:

```
FUN <- function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) 
     return(median(x))
  else 
     x <- sort(as.character(x))
  rl1 <- rle(x)
  rl1$val[which.max(rl1$le)]
  }

as.data.frame(lapply(tab, FUN))
aggregate(tab, by=list(gl(1,nrow(tab))), FUN=FUN)
# even easier
bob <- lapply(tab, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) median(x) else x[median(as.numeric(x))])
as.data.frame(bob)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` with `if` branching:

```
y <- read.table(text = "Number Factor  
3      A
2      A
5      B", header = TRUE)

as.data.frame(lapply(y, function(x) {
if (is.numeric(x)) return (median(x))
else return(x[which.max(table(x))])
}))
```

Comment: I do not think that returns a mode, but rather would return the last level of a factor.

Comment: Simply edit it to use `which.max(table(x))` then it works. +1 from me

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
as.data.frame( lapply(dfrm, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) {
                            median(x) } else {
                            names(sort( table(x) , decreasing=TRUE )[1])
                                             })
              )
```